# How can I update php using zypper?

Tags: php, opensuse, php53

I'm currently running 5.3.17 and I'd like to update to the latest stable version. I've looked up a bunch of guides and they all have me doing it manually using wget. I'd like to do it all through zypper so that I can update it using 'zypper update' like I do with most everything else.

How can I update php to the latest stable using zypper?

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:
Add some repository with the version you want/need.

Option 2:
Build a rpm/package of your own from source and install/update this as often as you like.